# For loop, getting two successive files

Tags: java, file, loops

I am using for loop to get files in a file directory.
However, I want to take each file and its successive file as the input of my GetDiffs method. How can I achieve so?

Here is my code:

```
File folder = new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image");
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".png"))
       Diffs.GetDiffs( , );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a local variable to store the previous `File` :

```
File folder = new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image");
File prev = null;
for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
   if (fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
       if (prev != null)
           Diffs.GetDiffs(prev, fileEntry);
       prev = fileEntry;
   }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps me;)

Answer (score 0):

For geting files in a file directory with your choice extention just some changes you need i thing ERAN also put the ans.

```
 File f = null;
    for (File fileEntry : myFolderpath.listFiles()) {
       if (getfile.getName().endsWith(".yourfileextention")) {
           if (f != null){
               Diffs.GetDiffs(f, getfile);
        }else{
           f = getfile;
         }
       }      
    }
```